# Translation not working for Constant strings in Plugin

Tags: plugin-development, translation, localization, textdomain, xgettext

I want to translate constant strings in my plugin defined as: 
**define( 'CONSTANT', __( 'string-A', 'textdomain' ) );**.
The 'string-A' is available for translation and I have uploaded the mo files in the desired language including this string but in the WordPress it still reflects as English string. Translation is working for all other strings except the one defined as constants in my config file. Any idea why is this happening?

Comment: maybe because the textdomain is loaded after the plugin is loaded. https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference

Comment: 1. In my case, other strings that are not referenced from constants are being shown in the local language.   2. I am laoding text-domain before using add_action( 'plugins_loaded', plugin_load_textdomain'); where plugin_load_textdomain function calls load_plugin_textdomain() function

Comment: To add the way I am using this constant later is like $x= '<h4>'.CONSTANT_NAME.'<h4>' and then echo $x; .  Now since the translated value will be there in CONSTANT_NAME key, it should print translated string. But it's not happening

Comment: plugins_loaded runs after plugins are loaded, so any constant definitions will run before that. but i'm not clear on why you are using constants to begin with, you can just use __( 'string-A', 'textdomain' ) directly.

Comment: My intention is to put all strings in a config file named xyx_strings.php so it's easier to manage and it will also avoid maintaining duplicate strings if any. That's why I want to use constants. So is it not possible to use constants for translation? Also, how does the constant value got entered in POT file? (Does execution flow of gettext to find all translation ready strings is different from the one when the will be displayed on site?)

Comment: i haven't really worked with language files, but you can probably just define a global (possibly array) variable or variables and then populate it/them after textdomain has been loaded using the appropriate hook. If you want to protect it, you can make the array a private class variable and provide a get method that takes the array key as a parameter.

Comment: Ok. So another question as I asked above"Can't we use strings defined as PHP constants if we want to translate them in a plugin?"

Comment: ok so I thought you can't define constants inside a function but you can https://stackoverflow.com/a/13672338/1228379 so you can just do that inside the function attached to the hook. I'm fairly sure you can use constants for strings since it is picking up the default language value in any case.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64116/discussion-between-nishant-garg-and-inarilo).